# Phaser : Problem setCollisionByProperty when use multiple Scene

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am a debutante in Phaser. I try to make a mini-RPG Game.  I have made my map and exported it as a .json object and use setCollisionByProperty to make the collision between my Sprite and Tile.
When i test it in solo scene, it works. But when i want to use multiple scene there are an error when i want to return to a scene.

> Uncaught TypeError: n is undefined

After multiple test, I located the probleme when I use setCollisionByProperty but i don't understand how resolve it

Here is the code :

```
import GameScene from "./GameScene.js"

import maisonScene from "./maisonScene.js"

import Joueur from "./joueur.js"

/*  * Configuration du jeu  */


var config = { type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    physics :{
        default : 'arcade',
        arcade:{
            debug : true, //Pour debug les collisions
            gravity :{
                y:0
            },
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    },
    pixelArt: true,
    scene : [maisonScene, GameScene], };

var game = new Phaser.Game(config); export let joueur = new Joueur();

function preload(){}

function create(){}

function update(){}
```

In the GameScene (is the same in maisonScene):

```
let staticLayer =[] //tableau contenant les calques du paysage 

export default class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene{
constructor(){
    super({key : "GameScene"})
}

create(){
//chargement de la carte
    const carteDuNiveau = this.add.tilemap("carte");

    //chargement des tuiles
    const tileset = carteDuNiveau.addTilesetImage("Citique","tuiles");

    //chargement du calque sol
    staticLayer.push(carteDuNiveau.createLayer("sol",tileset));   

    //chargement du calque chemin
    staticLayer.push(carteDuNiveau.createLayer("chemin",tileset));

    //chargement du calque fleurs
    staticLayer.push(carteDuNiveau.createLayer("fleurs",tileset));

player = this.physics.add.sprite(300, 150, 'player');
player.body.setSize(40,22,false) //Redimensionner la hitbox du joueur
player.body.setOffset(4,42) //Deplacer la hitbox vers le bas du joueur
player.setScale(0.6);
        
staticLayer.forEach((element)=>{
    element.setScale(2);
    
    element.setCollisionByProperty({ estSolide: true });
    
    // ajout d'une collision entre le joueur et les calques   
    this.physics.add.collider(player, element);
})
```

staticLayer contains all my layers

Thanks for your help
(Sorry for my bad english, i'm french)

Comment: Can you show how `staticLayer` is created? Is it an array, and if so what Object type elements are in it?

Comment: staticLayer is an array. it's created before the scene's class. (view edit in my post)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I found my error.
It's like you said : the error is my variable staticLayer. It need to restart with the scene because when the scene restart, it keep the first scene's layer in memory.
So I place my variable in create() to make the array empty when the scene start again :

```
create(){
staticLayer = []
```

and no more error !

thank you again

Comment: great that it works. I would still recommend, not to use too many global variables, if they can be avoided. 

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you find/debug it *(and my info is too long for a comment)*.

Well, I tested this structure in a small demo, and it works. So I must assume,
the Error is thrown there, but is probably caused somewhere else. It might be the switching of the Scenes, but without seeing the code I can't say. Thats why I would suggest not to use a global Variable but a property to collect the layers.

***Here some alterations, that you could do, that might solve the problem:***

1. Remove this line:

   ```
   let staticLayer = []
   ```
2. Setup the new property:

   ```
   export default class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene{
       constructor(){
           super({key : "GameScene"})
           this.staticLayer = [];
       }
       ...
   ```
3. replace all `staticLayer` for`this.staticLayer`:

   ```
   ...
   this.staticLayer.push(carteDuNiveau.createLayer("sol",tileset));   
   ...
   staticLayer.forEach((element) => {
       ...
   })
   ...
   ```

If this doesn't help, you would have to check the code, where you are switching Scenes.